# WYSIWYG WYMEditor - Cant get to load

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, wymeditor

This is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y6Lc4/

This is my load code:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.wymeditor').wymeditor();
});
​
```

Why oh why does this not work?! I've copied the code from the demo site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsfiddle has two problems:

1. According to [Issue 365](https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor/issues/365), WYMeditor 1.0.0b3 doesn't work with jQuery 1.8.x in Chrome/Safari. You'll have to either use a different versions of jQuery, a different browser, or wait for 1.0.0b4.
2. Because of the same-origin policy with regards to AJAX, you can't actually load WYMeditor using source hosted somewhere else. This is a limitation of browser security and the method that WYMeditor uses to load skins and translation files within its iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't loaded the jQuery library...

you can download it from here [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)

then add it before your editor. Or if you prefer, link from the Google developers site

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Update:

There demo site shows you need JQuery too... this is from the source [on this page](http://files.wymeditor.org/wymeditor/examples/01-basic.html)

```
<!-- jQuery library is required, see http://jquery.com/ -->
```

Comment: It is being loaded apparently (look in the left sidebar). I added it manually and it didnt make a difference:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y6Lc4/1/

Comment: Nice catch JcFx. Didn't think to check that part myself

Comment: @Darren Hmm, but it worked once, then I reloaded and it failed. Never used that editor so not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Haven't used it either, doesn't seem to fail this end though?